# AttributeError: 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'stop'

Tags: pandas

I'm using a library that gives me access to a RangeIndex object while iterating. I'm having trouble finding out how to access the integer index from this object. If i print the object i see that the "stop" parameter seems to be the index i want (not sure though). However when i try to print the stop parameter i get this error message. Though when i look at source code i see that all instances of RangeIndex look to have this parameter. I tried searching up how to get an index for RangeIndex and there isn't much on this particular object.

Comment: what version of pandas are you using?  You may want to try `_stop`.  `_stop` has been deprecated in favor of `stop` but for older versions `stop` might not exist.

Comment: that worked. thanks